# Is using const_cast for read-only access to a const object allowed?

Tags: c++, casting, constants, undefined-behavior, const-cast

In C++ I have a function that only requires read-only access to an array but is mistakenly declared as receiving a non-const pointer:

```
size_t countZeroes( int* array, size_t count )
{
    size_t result = 0;        
    for( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
       if( array[i] == 0 ) {
           ++result;
       }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and I need to call it for a const array:

```
static const int Array[] = { 10, 20, 0, 2};

countZeroes( const_cast<int*>( Array ), sizeof( Array ) / sizeof( Array[0] ) );
```

will this be undefined behaviour? If so - when will the program run into UB - when doing the const_cast and calling the functon or when accessing the array?

Comment: I suppose you cannot change the function declaration... but I strongly urge you to write a wrapper with a better one and do the dirty work inside it.

Comment: Maybe try a different thing altogether: `size_t numZeros = std::count(Array, Array + sizeof(Array)/sizeof(Array[0]), 0);`

Comment: @MP24 This function is just a simple illustration of a problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the undefined behavior when using const\_cast<>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535863/where-is-the-undefined-behavior-when-using-const-cast)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, it is allowed (if dangerous!). It's the actual write to a `const` object that incurs undefined behaviour, not the cast itself (7.1.5.1/4 [dcl.type.cv]).

As the standard notes in 5.2.11/7 [expr.const.cast], depending on the type of the object an attempt to write through a pointer that is the result of casting away `const` may produce undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Since your code does not modify the array, and you told the compiler you know what you are doing by using the `const_cast`, you will actually be OK.  However, I believe you are technically invoking undefined behaviour.  Best to get the function declaration fixed, or write, declare and use the const-safe version of it.

Comment: try reading up on how to use const in "Effective C++" or "More Effective C++". It shows some valid uses of the const_cast as well (e.g. to avoid some code duplication).

Comment: -1 because this is not undefined behavior; historically, it would have made C++98 code difficult to interoperate with pre-standard C.  However, I'm fully with you on the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that.  No, it is not undefined behavior as long as the function truely does not try to write to the array.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of `const_cast` is always the same -- it allows you to "break the rules", just like casting to and from `void*` -- sure you can do that, but the question is why should you?

In this case it's of course ok, but you should ask yourself why didn't you declare `size_t countZeroes( const int* array, size_t count )` in the first place?

And as a general rule about `const_cast`:

1. It may produce hard to find bugs
2. You're throwing away the const-agreement with the compiler
3. Basically you're turning the language into a lower-level one.

Answer (score -2):

Using `const_cast` on an object which is initially defined as `const` is UB, therefore the undefined behaviour comes about immediately at the point you call `const_cast`.

Comment: No. UB is at the moment of writing to a const object, not removing constness.

Comment: Oh right, sorry I got some conflicting advice on the interwebs