# Where is the undefined behavior when using const_cast<>?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, const-cast

If I do:

```
const char* const_str = "Some string";

char* str = const_cast<char*>(const_str); // (1)

str[0] = "P"; // (2)
```

Where (which line) exactly is the undefined behavior ?

I've been searching a lot for this on SO but haven't found any explicit and precise answer (or at least, none that I could understand).

Also related: if I use an external library which provides this kind of function:

```
// The documentation states that str will never be modified, just read.
void read_string(char* str);
```

Is it ok to write something like:

```
std::string str = "My string";

read_string(const_cast<char*>(str.c_str()));
```

Since I know for sure that `read_string()` will **never** try to write to `str` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it allowed to cast away const on a const-defined object as long as it is not actually modified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504247/is-it-allowed-to-cast-away-const-on-a-const-defined-object-as-long-as-it-is-not)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Line (2) has undefined behaviour. The compiler is at liberty to place constants in read-only memory (once upon a time in Windows this would have been a "data segment") so writing to it might cause your program to terminate. Or it might not.

Having to cast const-ness away when calling a poorly-defined library function (non-const parameter which should be const) is, alas, not unusual. Do it, but hold your nose.

Comment: "Do it, but hold your nose."  Consider doing it once in a wrapper function, so all the distributed call sites can at least avoid that ugliness.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Do you have any source to strengthen your last claim ? I am designing a C++ wrapper around OpenSSL (which unfortunately suffers from serious interface inconsistencies) and I'd like to be sure that my code won't be a cause of undefined behavior.

Comment: C++ standard Section 5.2.11#7 indicates that a *write operation* results in undefined behavior. Read operations should thus be safe.

Comment: My last claim amounts to: Cast away const-ness if you trust the function that you are calling, so you'll have to satisfy yourself that the function is safe. const_cast isn't doing any magic under the hood; const_cast won't change the pointer or the data that it points to. You can't cause an error here by casting alone, but are removing a (usually) useful compiler safety check.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation and rationale. Very good answer. Both upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score -1):

You are attempting to modify a constant string which the compiler may have put into a read-only section of the process.  This is better:

```
char str[32];
strcpy(str, "Some string");
str[0] = "P";
```

Comment: No offense, but that doesn't exactly answer my question: I know it is bad, and If my intent is to modify a string, I will not declare it `const` in the first place. The real question is more: "Do I really have to copy my string first to use it with a poorly designed interface or is the cast acceptable ?"

Comment: As RobH has pointed out - it's on line (2) - the line where you modify the buffer that is potentially in read-only memory.

Comment: @ereOn: the fact that C++ allows you to write `char* x = "abc"`, and hence is able to compile and run old C code without undefined behaviour, is evidence that there's no undefined behaviour until a write is actually attempted.